# bounded subset of $\mathcal{C}^1(\Omega)$ is precompact in $\mathcal{C}^0(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, function-spaces

I have to prove the following statement:

Assume that $\Omega$ is a open domain in $\mathbb{R}^N, N \in \mathbb{N}$. Let A be a bounded subset of $\mathcal{C}^1(\Omega)$ then A is precompact in $\mathcal{C}^0(\Omega)$.

Because every sequence in $\mathcal{C}^0(\Omega)$ has to be bounded, I thought about proving the statement in a similar way to the theorem of Bolzano Weierstrass, but I'm not sure how or if that works.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You are on the right track, it is indeed a consequence of Weierstrass approximation theorem. They key is first make sure that $C_1$ separates points in $\Omega$ and to relax the compactness assumption in the Weirstrass theorem. For the former, bump function will do the job; for the second, a one point compantufication argument and the fact that open sets in R^n$ are locally compact Hausdorff will do. If further questions, droop a message.